# Add object property from input.value

Tags: javascript, object, input, properties

Say I have an object with states as properties and an html input text field.

```
<input id="input" type="text">
```

---

```
var foo = {
    "Wisconsin" : "Madison",
    "Illinois" : "Springfield"

}
```

How can I add properties to foo using the input text field ?
I tried this :

```
 foo[input.value] = input.value;
```

but of course it didn't work...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to add a button or at least a change listener to monitor change in input and then update `foo` by getting new value entered in text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo.newValue = input.value
```

You are dealing with an object not an array.

So this will result in

{
    "Wisconsin" : "Madison",
    "Illinois" : "Springfield",
    "newValue" : VALUE-OF-INPUT-FIELD

}

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mk1quow/7/)

Comment: You can access properties in javascript with bracket notation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: While that might well be true, even in that case, his nomenclature is wrong....in that case it would be foo[newValue]....by doing it the way he is trying....it is an array call.

Comment: The "foo.newValue = input.value" works ! Thanks. Is there a way to first define the property name with an empty value by entering some text in the input, then enter another text to define the value ?

Comment: Yes of course there is....but you've been given enough that you should be able to figure out the rest for class. :)....like how about two input fields?

Comment: Indeed. I'm just unsure of how to proceed as I need to use a single input for this. I'll run some tests and come back here if I'm still stuck. Thanks for your help

Comment: you could allow input like newValue:myValue and then do a string split on the field and name.

Comment: I updated my fiddle to illustrate this.  https://jsfiddle.net/1mk1quow/7/

Answer (score 1):

To use normal javascript functions you can use:

```
foo.input = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

Or you can use jQuery:

```
foo.input = $('#input').val();
```

---

Input Box Value Property: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

jQuery .val(): http://api.jquery.com/val/